# What's the difference between 'git rm --cached', 'git restore --staged', and 'git reset'

Tags: git, github, staging, git-reset, git-rm

I have come across the following three ways in order to unstage the files that were staged by the command 'git add'

```
git rm --cached <file>
git restore --staged <file>
git reset <file>
```

Their behaviors looked completely same when I ran those commands one by one.
What exactly are the differences between them?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Two are the same; one is not, except under particular circumstances.

To understand this, remember that:

- a commit holds a snapshot of all files that Git knew about, as of the form they had when you said to commit them;
- the snapshot is made *from* the files that are in Git's index, aka staging-area, aka cache (three terms for the same thing); and
- `git add` means *make the copy in the index/staging-area/cache match the copy in my working tree* (by copying from the working tree if the working tree copy is updated, or by removing from the index if the working tree copy is removed).

So the index / staging-area contains, at all times, your *proposed next commit*, and was initially seeded from your *current commit* when you did a `git checkout` or `git switch` to obtain that commit.<sup>1</sup>  Your working tree thus contains a *third* copy<sup>2</sup> of each file, with the first two copies being the one in the *current commit* aka `HEAD`, and the one in the index.

With that in mind, here's what each of your commands does:

- `git rm --cached file`: removes the copy of the file from the index / staging-area, without touching the working tree copy.  The proposed next commit now *lacks* the file.  If the current commit *has* the file, and you do in fact make a next commit at this point, the difference between the previous commit and the new commit is that the file is gone.
- `git restore --staged file`: Git copies the file from the `HEAD` commit into the index, without touching the working tree copy.  The index copy and the `HEAD` copy now match, whether or not they matched before.  A new commit made now will have the *same* copy of the file as the current commit.

  If the current commit *lacks* the file, this has the effect of *removing* the file from the index.  So *in this case* it does the same thing as `git rm --cached`.
- `git reset file`: this copies the `HEAD` version of the file to the index, just like `git restore --staged file`.

(Note that `git restore`, unlike this particular form of `git reset`, *can* overwrite the working tree copy of some file, if you ask it to do so.  The `--staged` option, without the `--worktree` option, directs it to write only to the index.)

**Side note:** many people initially think that the index / staging-area contains only changes, or only changed files.  This is not the case, but if you were thinking of it this way, `git rm --cached` would appear to be the same as the other two.  Since that's not how the index works, it's not.

---

<sup>1</sup>There are some quirky edge cases when you stage something, then do a new `git checkout`.  Essentially, if it's possible to keep a different staged copy in place, Git will do so.  For the gory details see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).

<sup>2</sup>The committed copy, and any staged copy, are actually kept in the form of an internal Git *blob object*, which de-duplicates contents.  So if these two match, they literally just share one underlying copy.  If the staged copy differs from the `HEAD` copy, but matches any—perhaps even many—other existing committed copy or copies, the staged copy shares the underlying storage with all those other commits.  So calling each one a "copy" is overkill.  But as a mental model, it works well enough: none can ever be overwritten; a new `git add` will make a new blob object if needed, and if nobody uses some blob object in the end, Git eventually discards it.

---

#### A specific example

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65434544/whats-the-difference-between-git-rm-cached-git-restore-staged-and-gi/65434709?noredirect=1#comment125450509_65434709), pavel_orekhov says:

> It is still not clear to me where "git rm --cached" and "git restore --staged" differ. Could you please show a series of commands with these 2 that exhibit different behavior?

Let's check out a specific commit in the Git repository for Git itself (clone it first if needed, e.g., from https://github.com/git/git.git):

```
$ git switch --detach v2.35.1
HEAD is now at 4c53a8c20f Git 2.35.1
```

Your working tree will contain files named `Makefile`, `README.md`, `git.c`, and so on.

Let's now *modify some existing file in the working tree:*

```
$ ed Makefile << end
> 1a
> foo
> .
> w
> q
> end
107604
107608
$ git status --short
 M Makefile
```

The `>` signs are from the shell asking for input; the two numbers are the byte counts of the file `Makefile`.  Note the output from `git status` is `SPACEMSPACEMakefile`, indicating that the *index* or *staging area* copy of `Makefile` matches the `HEAD` copy of `Makefile`, while the *working tree* copy of `Makefile` differs from the *index* copy of `Makefile`.

*(Aside: I accidentally added two `foo` lines while preparing the cut and paste text.  I'm not going to go back and fix it, but if you do this experiment yourself, expect slightly different outputs.)*

Let's now `git add` this updated file, then replace `foo` in the first line with `bar`:

```
$ git add Makefile
$ git status --short
M  Makefile
```

Note that the `M` has moved left one column, M-space-space-Makefile, indicating that the *index* copy of `Makefile` differs from the `HEAD` copy, but now the index and working tree copies match.  Now we do the foo-to-bar replacement:

```
$ ed Makefile << end
> 1s/foo/bar/
> w
> q
> end
107608
107608
$ git status --short
MM Makefile
```

We now have *two* `M`s: the `HEAD` copy of `Makefile` differs from the index copy of `Makefile`, which differs from the working tree copy of `Makefile`.  Running `git diff --cached` and `git diff` will show you exactly how each pairing compares.

```
$ git diff --cached
diff --git a/Makefile b/Makefile
index 5580859afd..8b8fc5a6d6 100644
--- a/Makefile
+++ b/Makefile
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
-# The default target of this Makefile is...
+foo
+foo
 all::
 
 # Define V=1 to have a more verbose compile.
$ git diff
diff --git a/Makefile b/Makefile
index 8b8fc5a6d6..96a787d50d 100644
--- a/Makefile
+++ b/Makefile
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-foo
+bar
 foo
 all::
```

Now, if we run `git rm --cached Makefile`, this will *remove the index copy of the file `Makefile` entirely*, and `git status` will change accordingly.  Because we have all these modifications going around Git demands the "force" flag as well:

```
$ git rm --cached Makefile
error: the following file has staged content different from both the
file and the HEAD:
    Makefile
(use -f to force removal)
$ git rm --cached -f Makefile
rm 'Makefile'
$ git status --short
D  Makefile
?? Makefile
```

We now have *no* file named `Makefile` in our *proposed next commit* in the index / staging-area.  However, the file `Makefile` still appears (with the first line reading `bar`) in the working tree (inspect the file yourself to see).  This `Makefile` is an *untracked file* so we get two output lines from `git status --short`, one to announce the impending demise of file `Makefile` in the next commit, and the other to announce the existence of the untracked file `Makefile`.

Without making any commit, we now use `git restore --staged Makefile`:

```
$ git restore --staged Makefile
$ git status --short
 M Makefile
```

The status is now space-M again, indicating that `Makefile` *exists in the index* (and therefore will be in the next commit), and furthermore, *matches the `HEAD` copy of Makefile*, so `git diff --staged`—which is another way to spell `git diff --cached`—will not show it (and indeed will show nothing).  The *working tree* copy remains undisturbed, and still contains the extra line `bar`, as `git diff` shows:

```
$ git diff --staged
$ git diff
diff --git a/Makefile b/Makefile
index 5580859afd..96a787d50d 100644
--- a/Makefile
+++ b/Makefile
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
-# The default target of this Makefile is...
+bar
+foo
 all::
 
 # Define V=1 to have a more verbose compile.
```

Again, the key to understanding all of this is:

- Every commit holds a *full snapshot of every file that Git knows about*.
- This snapshot exists, at all times, in Git's *index*, which Git also calls the *staging area*, or occasionally—now mostly in the `--cached` flag—the *cache*.  The `--staged` or `--cached` flag<sup>3</sup> generally means *do something with this index / staging-area*.  Commands like `git reset`, `git rm`, and `git add` *implicitly* work with the index / staging-area, although flags may modify this behavior somewhat; the `git restore` command has the explicit `--staged` and `--worktree` flags.
- Meanwhile, your working tree contains ordinary everyday files.  *These are the only files you can see and work with directly* (with your editor for instance); only *Git commands* can see and work with the committed and index copies of files.
- *Committed* copies of files can never be changed.  They are in those commits *forever* (or as long as those commits continue to exist): they are read-only.  However, the *index* copy of a file can be replaced wholesale, with `git add`, or patched, with `git add -p`, or removed entirely, with `git rm` or `git rm --cached`.
- Ordinary files are, well, ordinary files: all your ordinary commands work ordinarily on the ordinary files.  (And isn't it extraordinary how the ordinary word "ordinary" is now amusing?)
- Running `git commit` takes all the *index* copies and freezes them into a new snapshot.  So what you do, as you work in Git, is:

  - manipulate ordinary files, in ordinary ways;
  - `git add` them to update Git's index copy, to prepare the freeze; and
  - `git commit` the result, to freeze them for all time.

  This is the process for making a *new commit*, and if you change your mind and decide *not* to make a new commit, `git restore --staged` or `git reset` can be used to *re-extract* a committed copy into the index copy.  But `git rm` *removes an index copy entirely*.

So if and *only* if *removing the index copy entirely* puts things back the way they were (which can happen when some file is *new*), then "make the index copy match the nonexistent `HEAD` copy, by removing it" is a correct way to do what you want.  But if the `HEAD` commit contains a copy of the file in question, `git rm --cached the-file` is wrong.

---

<sup>3</sup>Note that `--cached` and `--staged` have the *same meaning* for `git diff`.  For `git rm`, however, there's simply no `--staged` option at all.  Why?  That's a question for the Git developers, but we can note that historically, in the distant past, `git diff` did not have `--staged` either.  My best guess is therefore that it was an oversight: when whoever added `--staged` to `git diff` did it, they forgot to add `--staged` to `git rm` too.

Comment: Consider `git restore` and `git reset --hard`, while they both alter working tree, `git restore` (without options) doesn't touch index. So can I assume `git restore --staged --worktree` is the same as `git reset --hard`?

Comment: @GordonBai: right (although `git restore` is focused on individual files within a commit/the-index/your-worktree, while `git reset --hard` refuses to accept any pathspec: it's always commit-wide).

Comment: It is still not clear to me where "git rm --cached" and "git restore --staged" differ. Could you please show a series of commands with these 2 that exhibit different behavior?

Comment: @pavel_orekhov: `git rm --cached` *removes* an index entry (without doing anything else). `git restore --staged` *writes* an index entry, or many index entries: the way this could achieve the same result is if when some index entry gets written with a value that means "do not include this file". There is such a value (the null OID) but there's no way to access it directly; you can get it *indirectly* in other ways due to the idea of a directory/file conflict. But these are the two that I say *are* different, as they normally are different. I'll add a specific example.